# Analyzing a drop in retention

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I'm trying to show why a retention figure dropped from 87.7% in 2015 to 83.3% in 2016.  The waterfall chart below shows a breakdown of retention rate change by center (130, 120, 040, etc).  The problem with this chart is that each center is given equal weight, when in reality, some centers have more students than others.  For example, both 130 and 120 dropped 10.7%, but 120 has twice the number of students as 130, so 120 is a larger contributor to the overall drop.  How can I account for the population size of each center, and in this way, show which ones are most responsible for the overall drop in retention?

[image: waterfall chart retention change]

Comment: I'm not clear on the question. Are you asking about analyzing the differences in retention or depicting it?

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.  I'm asking about analyzing the differences in retention.  How much does each center contribute to the drop according to the number of students?  There was a 4.4% drop from 2015 to 2016.  I'd like to be able to say, of the 4.4% drop, Center 130 is responsible for 0.2%, Center 120 for 2%, Center 040 for 1%, etc.  I think I need to multiply by the number of students in each center to arrive at the weighted change in retention.  Does that sound right?

Comment: I'd say that sounds right. Alternatively, divide the number of students dropped at each site by the original total N. Should get the same answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is exactly what I ended up doing.  I then subtracted the weighted retention rate for 2015 from 2016 for each site to see which sites were most responsible for the drop.  Is this simply a weighted average kind of technique?  Also, if you put your comments in an answer, I'll check the answer box on it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to calculate the attrition at each center directly. Divide the number of students lost to followup in 2016 at each center by the total 2015 N. That will break your 4.4% by center using absolute numbers without having to mess about with weighted averages.

Comment: And when doing this, please please try to shrink retention estimates toward the mean for locations with a smaller numerator

Comment: "please try to shrink retention estimates toward the mean for locations with a smaller numerator" -- would this be for future retention predictions?

Comment: It would be during the modeling phase. Include a varying intercept term for each site and use a multilevel model.